# Meaning of green ground symbols in Body and Equipment Mounting Manual ground point documentation

Tags: electrical, ground, diagram

The Ford Transit [Body and Equipment Mounting Manual](https://www.etis.ford.com/BEMM) documents ground points in a set of diagrams and tables starting in section 4.20.1 on page 211.  While most of the ground points illustrated in the diagram are coloured black, a few are green.  The significance of this colouring does not appear to be explained in the manual.

There is some, but not complete, overlap between the set of green ground points and the set of ground points denoted with asterisks in the table.  There are both green ground points that are not annotated with asterisks and ground points annotated with asterisks that are not green.  The meaning of the asterisk is also not completely clear but I think it is meant to indicate that these points are preferable in cases where it is necessary to use more than one eyelet per ground stud.

What does the green colouring on some of these ground points indicate?

[image: main diagram for ground points on van-style body]
[image: final page of table along with table notes]

Comment: They are recommended ground points that should be used.

Comment: As noted in the question, the manual also gives a set of recommended ground points that is different from the set of green ground points.

Answer (score 1):

The points in green are those that are for use with extra equipment that you may want to fit dvd, cd changer, cameras front & rear etc etc

They provide these as if you drill holes in the metal body you affect the paint treatment and therefore the warranty protection - if the vehicle is out of the warranty then that is not so much of an issue...

Comment: Meaning that the black-coloured ground points already have something connected to them?  In that case, why are there black ground points with asterisks?